# Class type could not be resolved

Tags: c++

I'm using eclipse with minGW. I have the following error: when I define `SO3 my_rotation;` in the file SE3.h I get
**type SO3 could not be resolved**. Here is the SE3.h file:

```
#ifndef SE3_H_
#define SE3_H_
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include "SO3.h"

class SE3
{

private:
    SO3 my_rotation;// <--- error is here
    cv::Vec3f my_translation;


};


#endif /* SE3_H_ */
```

and the SO3.h file where the class SO3 is defined:

```
#ifndef SO3_H_
#define SO3_H_

class SO3
{
public:
   SO3();
};


#endif /* SO3_H_ */
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: What compiler are you using ?

Comment: Is there another file that inadvertently defines `SO3_H_` before `SO3.h` is included, breaking the guard? (Copy-and-paste error perhaps?) I see nothing wrong with the code, as posted.

Comment: I'm using gcc for windows - minimalist GNU for windows (MingW)

Comment: @TypeIA I'll check that...

Comment: @PhonoDots With the minimalistic code you posted, the error is irrelevant.

Comment: @ Mahesh: the error is irrelevant for you - not for me.

Comment: @PhonoDots, that was not Mahesh point. If that code is your "Minimal working example" then it will give an error because SO3 has no definition. Which I am guessing it is not the problem, it is hard to tell from the minimal working example.